Image scaling issue with Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage when display DPI affects printing on Windows HDC (Print to PDF)
I’m encountering a problem while printing images using Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage on a Windows HDC created from the "Microsoft Print to PDF" driver. The core issue is that the printer output is being affected by the display's DPI scaling settings.
When the display DPI is set to the standard 96 DPI, the images are printed correctly. However, when the user changes the display DPI to 120 (text size 125%) or other non-standard values, the images are incorrectly scaled. For example, a source image of 100x100 pixels results in only around 80x80 pixels being printed on the page, as if GDI+ is incorrectly applying display scaling to the print output.
This scaling issue seems to specifically affect PNG files. For JPEGs, I’ve found that updating the EXIF data to set a DPI value (72, 96, 120, etc.) resolves the problem, allowing the image to print correctly even with the display DPI set to 120%. However, this trick doesn't work for PNGs since they lack DPI metadata.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Calling Gdiplus::Graphics::SetPageScale
Using Gdiplus::Graphics::ResetTransform

Neither of these resolved the issue. It seems like GDI+ is applying the display scaling factor to the image during the printing process, which shouldn’t happen.
Additional context: The application is running in compatibility mode because it’s about 20 years old.
Has anyone encountered this issue where the printer output is scaled based on the display DPI? Any workarounds or fixes, particularly for PNG files, would be greatly appreciated!

PNG files may include an EXIF chunk, and that chunk could, in theory, contain the resolution (pixels per units).  Have you tried it with PNG files from a variety of sources?
